# In Nix, how can I refactor this configuration?

Tags: functional-programming, nix

So I'm playing around with home-manager in NixOS for managing my dotfiles. I have something in one of my dotfiles that looks like this:

```
my_color0   = ${xrdb:color0}
my_color1   = ${xrdb:color1}
my_color2   = ${xrdb:color2}
my_color3   = ${xrdb:color3}
my_color4   = ${xrdb:color4}
my_color5   = ${xrdb:color5}
my_color6   = ${xrdb:color6}
my_color7   = ${xrdb:color7}
my_color8   = ${xrdb:color8}
my_color9   = ${xrdb:color9}
my_color10  = ${xrdb:color10}
my_color11  = ${xrdb:color11}
my_color12  = ${xrdb:color12}
my_color13  = ${xrdb:color13}
my_color14  = ${xrdb:color14}
my_color15  = ${xrdb:color15}
```

Since Nix is functional, I imagine there must be an easy way of making this more DRY. I can't seem to find a function that does the equivalent of Python's `range(0, 16)`. And I imagine there's a way to map over a template of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done. The `lib` attribute in Nixpkgs has a host of functions that come in handy from time to time.

I am a little bit concerned by your example, because rewriting this as an algorithm doesn't provide any value in my perspective. I will assume that such a solution does provide value in your actual problem.

Here's a little `nix repl` session with a solution:

```
~ $ nix repl '<nixpkgs>'
Welcome to Nix version 2.0.4. Type :? for help.

Loading '<nixpkgs>'...
Added 8623 variables.

nix-repl> :p lib.concatMapStringsSep "\n" (i: "my_color${toString i} = \${xrdb:color${toString i}}") (lib.range 0 15)   
"my_color0 = ${xrdb:color0}\nmy_color1 = ${xrdb:color1}\nmy_color2 = ${xrdb:color2}\nmy_color3 = ${xrdb:color3}\nmy_color4 = ${xrdb:color4}\nmy_color5 = ${xrdb:color5}\nmy_color6 = ${xrdb:color6}\nmy_color7 = ${xrdb:color7}\nmy_color8 = ${xrdb:color8}\nmy_color9 = ${xrdb:color9}\nmy_color10 = ${xrdb:color10}\nmy_color11 = ${xrdb:color11}\nmy_color12 = ${xrdb:color12}\nmy_color13 = ${xrdb:color13}\nmy_color14 = ${xrdb:color14}\nmy_color15 = ${xrdb:color15}"
```

The `'<nixpkgs>'` argument loads all attributes from the `nixpkgs` in your `NIX_PATH`.

The `:p` command makes the printing of the value less lazy, but wasn't really necessary here, because a string can not be partially evaluated. When you're dealing with attrsets, you may want to use `:p`.

Other useful functions include `lib.concatStringsSep` and `map`.

Comment: Great! Where can I find documentation for nixpkgs `lib`?

Comment: Very few functions are [documented in the manual](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/index.html#chap-functions). Many of them do have inline documentation. You can find a function's definition site by attempting to evaluate the function without applying. For example: `nix-repl> lib.mapAttrs` will give you something of the form `«lambda @ /nix/store/somehash/nixos/lib/attrsets.nix:line:column»`